# How to use jQuery append to insert a HTML part contain an onclick function, and this function has a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example,

```
$(this).append('<div class="printText" id="'+inputVal +'">' + inputVal +
    '<img  onclick="removeItem('+ inputVal + ')" src="img/cross.png"height="25px" width="25px" style="float: right"></div>')
```

I want the `removeItem` function has a parameter `inputVal` from previous, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since what you add seems to be dynamic, it would be better to declare the event handler before the append occurs.

Lets say your container is defined like this:

> ```
> <div id="container"></div>
> ```

You could use something like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'img', function () {
   removeItem($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a better way to append elements, try something like this:

```
    $(this).append($('<div />').attr({
        'id': inputVal,
        'class': 'printText'
    }));
    $('#' + inputVal).append($('<img />')...now use functions to add src, id and so on);
```

Now add onClick handler:

```
   $('#imageId').onclick = removeItem(inputVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes around that value being passed in:

```
$(this).append(
    '<div class="printText" id="'+inputVal +'">' + inputVal +
    '<img onclick="removeItem(\'' + inputVal + '\')" src="img/cross.png"height="25px" width="25px" style="float: right"></div>'
    //                         ^^               ^^
);
```

PS Ideally, you should bind the event handler to the image, instead of putting it in an attribute directly.